# Excel VBA: A much needed alternative for GOTO statement

Tags: vba, excel, module, goto

I was creating an excel vba that has about say 20 modules(about 6 created and remaining under development).The code runs for a long time sometimes as it updates a minimum of 6 files to a maximum of upto 1200 files. The modules need to be updated in future so I have created a master module that goes through each of my modules and looks something like this :

```
Option Explicit

Sub CodeRunner()

Go_NoGo
'Module That decides when to run the Code and Sets the CDate.

CheckLastRunDate
'Module that checks when the code was last successfully Run.

DownloadListFile
'Downloads an updated list.csv file and makes some changes in it daily

 DownloadBRVFile
'Downloads an updated BRV.csv file and makes some changes in it daily

FileUpdater
'Updates multiple files based on Updated BRV.csv and list.csv

'========================================
'And So on many more modules
'========================================

LogWriterModule:
EndofCode

End Sub
```

What i wanted to do was that whenever a module is called it should perform its function and if it finds something extra ordinary

- **IT SHOULD SKIP THE REMAINING CODE within the current module**
- *and goto the LogWriterModule label in the master module*

I Totally understand jumping over modules is not a good programmng habbit but here This helps me avoid contamination of huge data after which someone can intervene manually what went wrong with the help of logs..
I have an average knowledge of programming, but this is my somewhat 1st mega excel vba project
What I initially tried was I had used a GOTO statement to call the LogWriterModule in these separate modules but later came to know that the label must exist in the same module... 
Has anyone any idea how can i achieve this without the use goto statements without the use of repetitive code that i may need to introduce as a last resort in my Master module ?
(i have a idea but its not a good solution to my problem. something like introducing a flag and checking it every time before the next module is called... )

Comment: You can make each Sub responsible for writing its own log output.  If you also make each one into a function, it can return True if all is OK, so you can then do something like `If Not CheckLastRunDate() Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Tim this method can't be used bcas each module is using global array(designed specially for the logwriter) in which a few values are stored.. this values are continuously replaced by the forthcoming module and in the end the logwriter uses these values to determine what to print... Actually the logwriter is somewhat meant for writing logs but as acts as a Decision Support System(DSS) if the code runs successfully... thanks for ur idea though it has triggered something new in my mind :)

Comment: Can you clarify: if a fault is detected within a sub-module (e.g., `Go_NoGo`), what gets skipped? The remaining code in `Go_NoGo`? The remaining calls in `CodeRunner`? Also, does `LogWriterModule:` do something or is it just a jumping out point?

Comment: If you're processing potentially over a thousand files then you really should be logging as you go, not waiting until the end to write out the log: for example what if a crash occurred on the very last file which ended up resetting your globals?  You wouldn't have any way to know how much data your routines had processed.